# missing 1 required positional argument: 'times' in function

Tags: python, tkinter

I keep getting the error:

```
missing 1 required positional argument: 'times'
```

While my code is:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

top = tk.Tk()

top.geometry("200x100")

def helloCallBack(times):
   times = times + 1
   messagebox.showinfo( "Clicked!!1", "Hello World")
   print("Clicked button " + str(times) + " times")
   

B = tk.Button(top, text ="Hello", command = helloCallBack)
B2 = tk.Button(top, text="Exit", command=top.destroy)

B2.pack(pady=20)
B.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

I tried to find an answer, but they used classes so I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: I shouldn't be using "camelCase."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`times` shouldn't be a parameter to the function, it should be a global variable so it keeps its value between calls.

```
times = 0

def helloCallBack():
    global times
    times = times + 1
    messagebox.showinfo( "Clicked!!1", "Hello World")
    print("Clicked button " + str(times) + " times")
```

Comment: now I got another problem ```UnboundLocalError: local variable 'times' referenced before assignment```

Comment: You forgot the `global times` line.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with the above answer. If you want to maintain how many times the button is clicked, you have to take out the `times` variable from the function.

BUT if you really need to pass args to method, you should use lambda or partials.

https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python-tkinter/how-to-pass-arguments-to-tkinter-button-command/

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

top = tk.Tk()

top.geometry("200x100")

def helloCallBack(times):
    times = times + 1
    messagebox.showinfo("Clicked!!1", "Hello World")
    print("Clicked button " + str(times) + " times")


B = tk.Button(top, text="Hello", command=lambda: helloCallBack(0))
B2 = tk.Button(top, text="Exit", command=top.destroy)

B2.pack(pady=20)
B.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: This will say that it was clicked 1 time every time, instead of counting up.

Comment: Primitive type argument is passed by value, so changes on `times` will be vanished after function exits.  Also you passed `0` whenever the button is clicked which is meaningless.